# BigQuery - Create STRUCT from multiple rows of a dictionary table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to use the following table, let's call it `fields`:

| field_name | risk |
| --- | --- |
| full_name | medium |
| email | high |
| address | high |
| ip_address | low |

to create a `STRUCT` structure that I could then fill out with data. Think about this as a schema for the struct, but I'm not sure if it's possible?

What I would like is this:

```
STRUCT (
  "" AS full_name,
  "" AS email,
  "" AS address,
  "" AS ip_address
)
```

Then I was hoping I would be able join it with data using `CROSS JOIN` and fill out those that exist but also not sure if this is the right approach.

I want to create those Structs but based on a predefined schema that could change, rather than writing it line by line

```sql
SELECT
  base_data.id,
  -- Not sure how I could use struct_tx.full_name to be updated with value from base_data
FROM base_data
  CROSS JOIN struct_tx
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not very straightforward in SQL but you can try this:

**Define struct**

```
WITH struct_cte AS (
  SELECT
    STRUCT(
      "" AS full_name,
      "" AS email,
      "" AS address,
      "" AS ip_address
    ) AS empty_struct
)
```

Then in the **CROSS JOIN** with `struct_tx`, do this using `COALESCE`

```
SELECT
  base_data.id,
  STRUCT(
    COALESCE(base_data.full_name, struct_cte.empty_struct.full_name) AS 
    full_name,
    COALESCE(base_data.email, struct_cte.empty_struct.email) AS email,
    COALESCE(base_data.address, struct_cte.empty_struct.address) AS address,
    COALESCE(base_data.ip_address, struct_cte.empty_struct.ip_address) AS ip_address
  ) AS filled_struct
FROM
  base_data
  CROSS JOIN struct_cte
```

Comment: I think there's no way to do it without dynamic SQL right? I would like to avoid writing the struct again and instead do it dynamically